# How can I make sure my remote repository has the correct access permissions?

Tags: git, ssh, repository, remote-access

I try to view my remote branches:

```
git fetch --all
```

I get the error message:

```
fatal: '/html/project' does not appear to be a git repository 
Could not read from remote repository. 
Please ensure that the correct access permissions exist and the repository exists.
```

So I logged in via ssh to my server and navigated to my folder `/html/project` and typed `git status`.

I get a git output so html/project is a git repository. I also checked the folder permissons of the folder `html/project`:

```
drwxrwxr-x 11
```

So why are these error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> git fetch --all
> ```

This means "fetch from all remotes".  How many remotes do you have?  What are their URLs?  (Use `git remote -v` to list them.)

> I get the error message:
>
> ```
> fatal: '/html/project' does not appear to be a git repository 
> Could not read from remote repository. 
> Please ensure that the correct access permissions exist and the repository exists.
> ```

This means that at least one of your remotes—we won't know which one(s) until you run `git remote -v` to list them—has `/html/project` as its (Git-extended-style) URL.  Or—here's the tricky bit—perhaps one of them has `ssh://<ssh-part>/html/project`.

> So I logged in via ssh to my server ...

That's fine, but it misses out on the tricky part.

> ... and [`/html/project` on that computer is a Git repository]

It sounds like your URL should be `ssh://your.server.full.dns.name.goes.here//html/project` or similar, rather than just `/html/project`.  (Whether you need a user name here depends on how your ssh login to this server works.)

Note the double slash!

You mention in comments that the URL is:

> ```
> ssh://myuser@myhost.de:2222/html/sulu
> ```

(for both fetch and push), and that's the problem.  Even with the `ssh://myuser@myhost.de:2222` part, which directs your Git to (in effect) use `ssh -p 2222 myuser@myhost.de` to get *to* the remote, the URL your Git provides to `myuser@myhost.de` is not `/html/sulu` but rather `html/sulu`.

Git isn't really aware of all of this—it doesn't do a lot of fancy parsing work—so *Git* thinks it's presenting `/html/sulu`, but it isn't.  It's presenting `html/sulu`.

When ssh connects to another machine, you start out with your *current working directory* being your *home directory*.  For instance, my home directory is `/home/torek` (Linux) or `/Users/torek` (macOS).  So any *relative* URL, as for:

```
ssh://my.host.name/src/proj
```

refers to `/home/torek/src/proj` or `/Users/torek/src/proj`.  But you want `/html/sulu`, something *not in your home directory*.

You can typically get there by using the double slash trick: `ssh://myuser@myhost.de:2222//html/sulu`.  The ssh code strips off one slash, leaving `/html/sulu` as the path, which then works.

Sometimes the ssh system *doesn't* let you do this—it's all up to ssh; none of it is up to Git—and in that case you may need to use some other trick, such as making a symbolic link in your home directory on the server.

Comment: when I try `ssh -v -p 2222 myuser@myhost.de` the connection works: debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey)., Authenticated to myhost.de ([194.118.254.55]:2222). but when I try `git fetch --all` I get the error The authenticity of host '[myhost.de]:2222 ([194.118.254.55)' can't be established.`

Comment: I tried `git remote -v` as you suggested. The result is `origin ssh://myuser@myhost.de:2222/html/sulu (fetch)
origin ssh://myuser@myhost.de:2222/html/sulu (push)`

Comment: Aha, there's the problem: `ssh://myuser@myhost.de:2222/html/sulu` => "connect to myuser@myhost.de on port 2222, then look for `html/sulu`. NOT `/html/sulu`, but `html/sulu`. Note the double slash in my suggested URL. Let me update the answer above as well, as there's a subtle bit of trickery here.